# How do I change the text of a <p> with a button in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, single-page-application

For my amusement and practice, I am making a simple random insult generator. I plan to separate my elements out into components and dry the code. I am trying to make an `event handler` that will update the text of my `<p>` element with a new random word. I have made an attempt to add a function inside of the `App` component, and a`console.log` of `'button clicked'` was successful. How do I grab the`<p className="randomInsultText">` and display the random text there?

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import image from "./callthema.png";
import words from "./data";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <img src={image} alt="meme" width="50%" />
        <h2>Call em' a</h2>

        <p className="randomInsultText">
          {words[0].setOne[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[0].setOne.length)] +
            " " +
            words[1].setTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[1].setTwo.length)]}
        </p>
     <button>New Word</button>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is a shortened version of the words from my data.js file:

```
export default [
  {
    setOne: ["Lazy", "Smelly", "Egg Headed", "Terrible"]
  },
  {
    setTwo: ["Goblin", "Dingbat", "Lunkhead", "Snowflake"]
  }
];
```

Comment: Have you looked into React `state` and `hooks`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `state` for updating value into the `react` app. `React functional component` has an awesome `hook`called [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). You can try this.

```
const [word, setWord] = useState(words[0].setOne[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[0].setOne.length)] + " " + words[1].setTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[1].setTwo.length)]);


<p className="randomInsultText">{word}</p>
<button onClick={setWord(words[0].setOne[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[0].setOne.length)] + " " + words[1].setTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[1].setTwo.length)])}>New Word</button>
```

Comment: Okay, I see how this is would work! Thank you very much. My app is compiling, however react is saying that there are too many re-renders.

Comment: Yes just had to change the value in the ```onClick``` to a function instead of passing in ```setWord()``` I used the solution from NiceRice's comment below. https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-mclaren-4l15c

Comment: Yes you should do it in a separate function. I just told you the path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use so called [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./App.css"
import image from "./callthema.png"
import words from "./data"

const App = () => {
  const [insult, setInsult] = useState(
    words[0].setOne[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[0].setOne.length)] +
      " " +
      words[1].setTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[1].setTwo.length)]
  )

  const randomizeInsult = () => {
    setInsult(
      words[0].setOne[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[0].setOne.length)] +
        " " +
        words[1].setTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * words[1].setTwo.length)]
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <img src={image} alt="meme" width="50%" />
        <h2>Call em' a</h2>

        <p className="randomInsultText">{insult}</p>
        <button onClick={() => randomizeInsult()}>New Word</button>
      </>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```